# Парсер PDF

Tags: pdf, php, парсер, синтаксический-анализ

Пробую вытянуть инфу из PDF файла, нашел [php-pdf-parser](https://github.com/adeel/php-pdf-parser) запустил пример - работает

```
include 'pdf-parser/pdf.php';

$pdf = new PdfFileReader(fopen('test.pdf', 'rb'));
print $pdf->page_count;
```

но кроме количества страниц ничего не могу вывести, инструкцию или примеры для этого скрипта найти не смог. в коде pdf.php тоже не смог разобраться

помогите запустить этот скрипт или посоветуйте другой. Спасибо!

Comment: главное, что бы pdf не был в виде картинок, тогда текст точно не вычитаете никакой.

Я правильно понимаю, что Вы только демку и запустили, а внутрь сорцов даже не смотрели?

Comment: пдф с текстом. Пробую запустить функции которые внутри в pdf.php, а в ответ только белый лист

Comment: Тот же вопрос. Нужно пропарсить PDF больше 10000 страниц. чем можно?

Answer (score 1):

Есть более известная и стабильная библиотека для PDF парсинга.

https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser

Документация:
http://www.pdfparser.org/documentation

```
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('document.pdf');
$pages  = $pdf->getPages();

foreach ($pages as $page) {
    echo $page->getText();
}
```

Comment: пользовался, тоже самое, что и у автора. количество страниц видит, текст пустой. у него есть демка, распознает текст не во всех файлах.